# Python printing Deepdiff value

Tags: python-2.7

I am using the `deepdiff` function to find the difference between 2 dictionaries, which gives the output as: `A = {'dictionary_item_added': set(["root['mismatched_element']"])}`. How to print just `'mismatched_element'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
set_item = A['dictionary_item_added'].pop()
print set_item[set_item.find("['")+2 : set_item.find("']")]
```

The first line gets the element from the set, the second removes the `[]` and everything around them, and prints.

This code does the specific task you asked for, but it's hard to generalize the solution without a more generalized question..

Comment: Danke Eran, to be more precise, i have 2 dict like this A= {V:1, H:4}, B= {K:3, V:1}. So, the deepdiff returns the key which are not common in both the dict. The format in which deepdiff returns as, C = {'iterable_item_added': {'root[01]': 'K}, {'root[02]': 'H}}, I just want the value K and H.

Comment: there is no fixed result, so the main idea is to pick up the key name listing in the output of the function.